# Can a geofence contain many other geofences

Tags: ios, geolocation, location

We are developing an app that depends on geofencing and locations. 
What I dont understand is , can a Geofence exist INSIDE another geofence?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can have a geofence region with a radius that contains other geofences within that radius.

For example:

If we add a geofence region A with center point  to X,Y and radius to 100km.

We can add a second geofence region B with center point to A,B and radius to 1km. Is valid that A,B point is inside the first geofence region radius range added.

If this is the case then when you enter the second geofence region B, you should get GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER event for both since are inside the first geofence region radius range.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can. Geofence events are triggered whenever a geofence boundary is crossed. So technically iOS does not mind geographic complexities such as an overlap or inside.